# How to fit Erdos-Renyi, Watts-Strogatz and Barabasi-Albert models to a network?

Tags: python, networkx

I am learning some basic knowledge about **Complex Dynamic Networks**, and doing an assignment which is related to network models. In this assignment we have to implement several models on our network, and then decide which one is better for our network, and is a better modeling method. This is a part of assignment:

> • Fit ER, WS, BA, and X models to your network
>
> – Select (find) X as the best fitting model
>
> – Generate artificial graphs similar to that networks
>
> • Specify the suitable generative parameters

I have a network which has been provided in [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-Vote.html). This dataset consists of two columns; `FromNodeId`, and `ToNodeId`. I have converted it to a graph using `networkX` library  in **python**, and calculated some other parameters of it. The full code which I have implemented is in this [repo](https://github.com/AylinNaebzadeh/Complex-Dynamic-Network/blob/main/Assignment%20%232/Assignment_2_Wiki_Vote.ipynb).

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_edgelist("Wiki-Vote.txt", nodetype=int, create_using=nx.DiGraph(), comments='#')
```

But, I don't know how can I fit these models into my network, and then decide which one is better for my network. I have searched for this problem, but I could not find a related answer. I have also seen the predefined methods in `networkX` library, for these models. But only the [barabasi_albert_graph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.barabasi_albert_graph.html) takes an optional parameter which is for the initial graph.

I will be grateful for your help and answer on how to solve this problem, and compare these models for my dataset.